# Change colour based on class value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple script that I want to change the colour of text based on what it says.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    if ($('.js-stock-level').val() == 'Sorry Not In Stock') {
        $('.js-stock-level').css({ 'color': 'red', 'font-weight' : 'bold' });
    }
    else {
        $('.js-stock-level').css({ 'color': 'green', 'font-weight' : 'bold' });
    }
});

<p class="js-stock-level">Sorry Not In Stock</p>
<p class="js-stock-level">12 in Stock</p>
```

Programmatically it makes sense what I'm trying to achieve but it does not work. I feel its to do with multiple classes on the page and jQuery not knowing what element to select.

**Edit**

Here is the Razor

```
@if (item.StockLevel == 0)
                    {
                        <p class="js-stock-level">
                            @item.StockText
                        </p>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p class="js-stock-level">
                            @item.StockText
                        </p>
                        <p>£@item.Price inc VAT</p>

                        <span>Quantity: </span><input type="number" style="width:35px" value="1" min="1" /><br /><br />
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Add to basket</button>
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation

If you want to change some CSS properties of an element based on other attributes (like the text value in your example), you can use the [`.css(propertyName, function)`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function).

However, to simplify styling the element, i would recommend using CSS classes. In order to do change the class of an element we will use another **jQuery** method, the [`.addClass(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/#addClass-function).

## Example 1 - using .css(propertyName, function)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.js-stock-level').css('color', function(elm) {
    var text = $(this).text();
    return (text == 'Sorry Not In Stock' ? 'red' : 'green');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<p class="js-stock-level">Sorry Not In Stock</p>

<p class="js-stock-level">12 in Stock</p>
```

## Example 2 - using .addClass(function)

```js
var NOT_IN_STOCK_TEXT = 'Sorry Not In Stock',
  NOT_IN_STOCK_CLASS = 'not-in-stock';

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.js-stock-level').addClass(function() {
    return $(this).text() === NOT_IN_STOCK_TEXT ? NOT_IN_STOCK_CLASS : '';
  });

});
```

```css
.js-stock-level {
  color: green;
}
.js-stock-level.not-in-stock {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<p class="js-stock-level">Sorry Not In Stock</p>

<p class="js-stock-level">12 in Stock</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `val()` to `text()` and it will work.

Comment: Still seems to go straight to the else and set the colour to green

Answer (score 0):

As other Answers mentioned you have to use `.text()` instead of `.val()` and you said you have many elements with same class name and there is possibility that the element with text `Sorry Not In Stock` must be anywhere.

So when you have multiple elements with same class name **you must iterate over all elements like below**.

Hope this helps

```js
$('.js-stock-level').each(function(Index, Obj) {
  if ($(Obj).text() == "Sorry Not In Stock") {
    $(Obj).css({
      'color': 'red',
      'font-weight': 'bold'
    });
  } else {
    $(Obj).css({
      'color': 'green',
      'font-weight': 'bold'
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="js-stock-level">Sorry Not In Stock</p>
<p class="js-stock-level">12 in Stock</p>
```

**Update (According to RAZOR)**

```
@{
    var NoStockText = "Sorry Not In Stock";
    var StockText = "Sorry Not In Stock";
  }
<p @if(StockText==NoStockText){<text>style='color:red;'</text>}>@StockText</p>
```

And `StockText` is your `@item.StockText`

Comment: Hmm, this is the best answer yet. I'm not starting to think it also could be because the content is being generated using Razor (C#). So when this script runs it the jQuery is not catching it.

Comment: razor renders HTML in pageload, so write the above JS in `document.ready` and for your info you can achieve this in RAZOR without JS. give it a try  before using this code, because using this will give a glitch kind of thing to user, first it will be black or some default color then it becomes red, that doesn't look good.  @JohnCooling

Comment: @JohnCooling, i updated answer. i just used if condition only to show how you can achieve this in RAZOR.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this issue using Razor

See Working code below.

```
 @if (item.StockText == "Sorry Not In Stock")
                {
                    <p class="js-stock-level not-in-stock">
                        @item.StockText
                    </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p class="js-stock-level">
                        @item.StockText
                    </p>
                    <p>£@item.Price inc VAT</p>

                    <span>Quantity: </span><input type="number" style="width:35px" value="1" min="1" /><br /><br />
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Add to basket</button>
                }
```

Once I checked the text, I just added the Not In Stock css class to the element.